# Triying to play an Audio from the sdcard

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I write this because I have a problem when I choose an audio from the sdCard and I try to play it with MediaPlayer.

Here is part of my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Selecciona la música de Fondo "), PETICION_ESCOGER_AUDIO);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    musicaDeFondo.reset();
    if (requestCode == PETICION_ESCOGER_AUDIO)
    {

        Uri musicaFondoSeleccion = data.getData();
        if (musicaFondoSeleccion != null)
        {
            System.out.println(musicaFondoSeleccion.toString());
            // Here fails
            musicaDeFondo = (AndroidMusica) sonidoManager.nuevaMusicaSDCARD(Piano.this, musicaFondoSeleccion); // Here fails

        }

    }
}
```

And my AndroidMusica Class Constructor:

```
public AndroidMusica (Context ctx, Uri path){
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ctx, path);  // Here files. line 37
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        isPrepared = true;
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Log:

```
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=42, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/audio/media/434 }} to activity {com.psdmple.piano/com.psdmple.piano.Piano}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2997)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3040)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:128)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1191)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at logica.AndroidMusica.<init>(AndroidMusica.java:37)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at logica.SonidoManager.nuevaMusicaSDCARD(SonidoManager.java:60)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at com.psdmple.piano.Piano.onActivityResult(Piano.java:101)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2993)
02-19 02:31:24.792: E/AndroidRuntime(19447):    ... 11 more
```

I would really appreciate your help =)

Comment: what is line number `37` in AndroidMusica.java ?

Comment: Do you get the data in on activity result?

Comment: Yes!! Unless I was wrong, Data is get from onActivityResult. The problem is when I set Data to the MediaPlayer:                                             mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ctx, path);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `mediaPlayer` is never initiated with a constructor, and is therefor null.

Comment: Yeeep! Thank you! I forget to initializate it!!  =)